# openGL superbible source code compilation error

Tags: c++, c, opengl, g++, glfw

I've just started to learn openGL programming with the openGL Superbible. Unfortunately I'm not able compile any example. I'm on Ubuntu 18.10 and I prepared the development environment with these packages from the official repository:

- mesa-common-dev (with these package you get header files in /usr/include/GL/)
- libglfw3-dev (header files in /usr/include/GLFW/)

The book uses a small framework with an entry point in the sb7.h header (in the book source code), sb7.h then points to glfw3 and gl3w (the latter given with the book's source code, so you don't need to download it).

This is the first example from the book:

```
#ifndef _LINUX
#define _LINUX
#endif

// Include the "sb7.h" header file
#include "sb7.h"
// Derive my_application from sb7::application
class my_application : public sb7::application
{
public:
  // Our rendering function
  void render(double currentTime)
  {
    // Simply clear the window with red
    static const GLfloat red[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red);
  }
};
// Our one and only instance of DECLARE_MAIN
DECLARE_MAIN(my_application);
```

If I try to compile it (the file is called 'main.cpp') with `g++ main.cpp -lglfw` I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDOdloQ.o: in function `sb7::application::run(sb7::application*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x1c): undefined reference to `sb7::application::app'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x27e): undefined reference to `gl3wInit'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x29f): undefined reference to `gl3wIsSupported'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x2af): undefined reference to `gl3wDebugMessageCallback'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x2bd): undefined reference to `sb7::application::debug_callback(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, char const*, void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x2c9): undefined reference to `gl3wEnable'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x2de): undefined reference to `sb6IsExtensionSupported(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x2ee): undefined reference to `gl3wDebugMessageCallbackARB'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x2fc): undefined reference to `sb7::application::debug_callback(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, char const*, void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x308): undefined reference to `gl3wEnable'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDOdloQ.o: in function `sb7::application::glfw_onResize(GLFWwindow*, int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application13glfw_onResizeEP10GLFWwindowii[_ZN3sb711application13glfw_onResizeEP10GLFWwindowii]+0x15): undefined reference to `sb7::application::app'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application13glfw_onResizeEP10GLFWwindowii[_ZN3sb711application13glfw_onResizeEP10GLFWwindowii]+0x1c): undefined reference to `sb7::application::app'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDOdloQ.o: in function `sb7::application::glfw_onKey(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application10glfw_onKeyEP10GLFWwindowiiii[_ZN3sb711application10glfw_onKeyEP10GLFWwindowiiii]+0x1c): undefined reference to `sb7::application::app'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application10glfw_onKeyEP10GLFWwindowiiii[_ZN3sb711application10glfw_onKeyEP10GLFWwindowiiii]+0x23): undefined reference to `sb7::application::app'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDOdloQ.o: in function `sb7::application::glfw_onMouseButton(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application18glfw_onMouseButtonEP10GLFWwindowiii[_ZN3sb711application18glfw_onMouseButtonEP10GLFWwindowiii]+0x18): undefined reference to `sb7::application::app'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDOdloQ.o:main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application18glfw_onMouseButtonEP10GLFWwindowiii[_ZN3sb711application18glfw_onMouseButtonEP10GLFWwindowiii]+0x1f): more undefined references to `sb7::application::app' follow
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccDOdloQ.o: in function `my_application::render(double)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN14my_application6renderEd[_ZN14my_application6renderEd]+0x14): undefined reference to `gl3wClearBufferfv'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Reading the messages I thought that something was wrong with the gl3w library, so I downloaded it from the [github repository](https://github.com/skaslev/gl3w) and I put it and glcorearb.h in `/usr/include/GL/`, pointing the `#include` in sb7.h to that folder. Eventually I compiled gl3w.c and linked it to main.cpp with g++ as written here:

1. `g++ -c gl3w.c`
2. `g++ -c main.cpp`
3. `g++ gl3w.o main.o`

but when I execute 3) I get other errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: gl3w.o: in function `open_libgl()':
gl3w.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/bin/ld: gl3w.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/bin/ld: gl3w.o: in function `close_libgl()':
gl3w.c:(.text+0x6f): undefined reference to `dlclose'
/usr/bin/ld: gl3w.o: in function `get_proc(char const*)':
gl3w.c:(.text+0xc5): undefined reference to `dlsym'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `sb7::application::run(sb7::application*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x1c): undefined reference to `sb7::application::app'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x21): undefined reference to `glfwInit'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x7c): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x92): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0xb3): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0xd4): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0xe3): undefined reference to `glfwWindowHint'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o:main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0xf2): more undefined references to `glfwWindowHint' follow
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `sb7::application::run(sb7::application*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x13f): undefined reference to `glfwGetPrimaryMonitor'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x172): undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x1c8): undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x1e2): undefined reference to `glfwSetWindowSizeCallback'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x1fc): undefined reference to `glfwSetKeyCallback'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x216): undefined reference to `glfwSetMouseButtonCallback'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x230): undefined reference to `glfwSetCursorPosCallback'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x24a): undefined reference to `glfwSetScrollCallback'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x279): undefined reference to `glfwSetInputMode'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x2af): undefined reference to `gl3wDebugMessageCallback'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x2bd): undefined reference to `sb7::application::debug_callback(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, char const*, void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x2c9): undefined reference to `gl3wEnable'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x2de): undefined reference to `sb6IsExtensionSupported(char const*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x2ee): undefined reference to `gl3wDebugMessageCallbackARB'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x2fc): undefined reference to `sb7::application::debug_callback(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, int, char const*, void*)'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x308): undefined reference to `gl3wEnable'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x339): undefined reference to `glfwGetTime'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x355): undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x35a): undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x372): undefined reference to `glfwGetKey'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x39b): undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x3e7): undefined reference to `glfwDestroyWindow'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_[_ZN3sb711application3runEPS0_]+0x3ec): undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `sb7::application::glfw_onResize(GLFWwindow*, int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application13glfw_onResizeEP10GLFWwindowii[_ZN3sb711application13glfw_onResizeEP10GLFWwindowii]+0x15): undefined reference to `sb7::application::app'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application13glfw_onResizeEP10GLFWwindowii[_ZN3sb711application13glfw_onResizeEP10GLFWwindowii]+0x1c): undefined reference to `sb7::application::app'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `sb7::application::glfw_onKey(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application10glfw_onKeyEP10GLFWwindowiiii[_ZN3sb711application10glfw_onKeyEP10GLFWwindowiiii]+0x1c): undefined reference to `sb7::application::app'
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application10glfw_onKeyEP10GLFWwindowiiii[_ZN3sb711application10glfw_onKeyEP10GLFWwindowiiii]+0x23): undefined reference to `sb7::application::app'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `sb7::application::glfw_onMouseButton(GLFWwindow*, int, int, int)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application18glfw_onMouseButtonEP10GLFWwindowiii[_ZN3sb711application18glfw_onMouseButtonEP10GLFWwindowiii]+0x18): undefined reference to `sb7::application::app'
/usr/bin/ld: main.o:main.cpp:(.text._ZN3sb711application18glfw_onMouseButtonEP10GLFWwindowiii[_ZN3sb711application18glfw_onMouseButtonEP10GLFWwindowiii]+0x1f): more undefined references to `sb7::application::app' follow
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `my_application::render(double)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN14my_application6renderEd[_ZN14my_application6renderEd]+0x14): undefined reference to `gl3wClearBufferfv'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

At this point I tried with the [single file version](https://github.com/gingerBill/gl3w-Single-File) of gl3w.h which already includes gl3w.c. I put the two headers in `/usr/include/GL/` and then I pointed sb7.h to that version of the library, but other errors appeared with `g++ main.cpp -lglfw`:

```
In file included from main.cpp:6:
sb7.h: In member function ‘virtual void sb7::application::run(sb7::application*)’:
sb7.h:137:9: error: ‘gl3wInit’ was not declared in this scope
         gl3wInit();
         ^~~~~~~~
sb7.h:137:9: note: suggested alternative: ‘glfwInit’
         gl3wInit();
         ^~~~~~~~
         glfwInit
sb7.h:147:17: error: ‘gl3wIsSupported’ was not declared in this scope
             if (gl3wIsSupported(4, 3))
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sb7.h:147:17: note: suggested alternative: ‘gl3w_is_supported’
             if (gl3wIsSupported(4, 3))
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                 gl3w_is_supported
```

I also added `#define GL3W_IMPLEMENTATION` before `#include "GL/gl3w.h"` as suggested in the documentation of the single file version of gl3w but with no luck.
I get the same errors with the other book's source codes.

Hope that someone can help me. 
Thank you.

Comment: All those `/usr/bin/ld` are linking errors and not compiler errors. So you do not link against different required libraries.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Does `g++ gl3w.o main.o -ldl` improve the situation?

Comment: @hidefromkgb not really, with g++ gl3w.o main.o -lglfw -ldl I get errors of undefined references with some GLFW functions.

Comment: @gaskotree Does it at least eliminate `undefined reference to dlopen`/`dlclose`/`dlsym`? If yes then we\`re getting somewhere, and all you need to get the whole thing working is linking to the project the remaining libraries it needs.